# Impossible to communicate Unity app with Android native code through a jar file

Tags: android, java-native-interface, unity-game-engine

what I want:

- The Unity app should show a notification in the action bar when the app has not been opened in the last 3 days.

what I've done in Android:

- I've made an Android Library that contains a MainActivity (extending "UnityPlayerActivity") that starts a Service. This service will calculate the time from the last use from the app. Dependes on this time, I will show a notification or not. The code is like this:

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      startService(new Intent(this, CheckTimeService.class));
  }

  public void setTime(long epochTime) {
      SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
          "time", MODE_PRIVATE);
      prefs.edit().putLong("time", epochTime).apply();

  }
  }
  ```

I've exported the Android library to a jar file and imported it into "Assets -> Plugins -> Android" in Unity Project path.

- what I've done in Unity (piece of code attached in the splash screen):

  ```
  void Awake(){
          System.DateTime epochStart = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
          long cur_time = (long)(System.DateTime.UtcNow - epochStart).TotalSeconds;

          AndroidManager.GetInstance().CallJavaFunc( "setTime",  cur_time); 
          Debug.Log ("Go");
  }
  ```

AndroidManager is referencing to this script (from a public github repository):

https://github.com/inbgche/Unity-Android-Communication/blob/master/RocketLauncher/Assets/Scripts/AndroidManager.cs

With this code, the Unity app crashes.

Any idea that what could be wrong?

----- UPDATE -------

Error log:

the method should be static? I'm calling it through curActivity.Call(), not curActivity.CallStatic()

> 11-18 16:48:20.774 12147 12184 I Unity   : AndroidJavaException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method with name='setTime'
>   signature='(J)V' in class Ljava.lang.Object;
>
> 11-18 16:48:20.774 12147 12184 I Unity   :
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method with name='setTime'
>   signature='(J)V' in class Ljava.lang.Object;
>
> 11-18 16:48:20.774 12147 12184 I Unity   :    at
>   com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.getMethodID(Unknown Source)
>
> 11-18 16:48:20.774 12147 12184 I Unity   :    at
>   com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
>
> 11-18 16:48:20.774 12147 12184 I Unity   :    at
>   com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a(Unknown Source)
>
> 11-18 16:48:20.774 12147 12184 I Unity   :    at
>   com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$b$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
>
> 11-18 16:48:20.774 12147 12184 I Unity   :    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>
> 11-18 16:48:20.774 12147 12184 I Unity   :    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>
> 11-18 16:48:20.774 12147 12184 I Unity   :    at
>   com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$b.run(Unknown Source)

---------- UPDATE 2 -------------

I've solved the errors log calling the method by this way:

```
AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.tyris.mylibrary.MainActivity");
unityPlayer.Call ("setTime", cur_time);
```

But now, in despite of the fact that the log not show any error, the service is not working.

Comment: Can you post the crash logs?

Comment: Please, post logs from adb

Comment: Updated with the error log. Thanks!

Comment: question updated one more time (Update 2)